# I want to integrate vimeo video with the app

Tags: vimeo-android

I want to connect vimeo video with an android app, the process is like this:

I want to upload the video on Vimeo, and want to see the list of video uploaded in the vimeo from the android app and play it from the android app.

In simple words I don't want to upload the link of every new video in my code.

Is that possible, help me with this
What sort of technology require for this
and what is the process ?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I am new to Android apps too. If you wish to save links you had already accessed, then I assume you should look at "Room" (The name of Android Internal Storage). Room would helps you to remember links/videos even if you close the app.

In regards listing items, I'd look at "RecyclerView".

I don't have enough knowledge on that field, to provide you with an accurate answer but I'd suggest start looking on these two topics.